# Solving partial differential equation with dimensional analysis

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the partial differential equation to solve
$$-y''+(y')^2-2y'/x=((e^y)/x^2)(\partial f/\partial z +a x),$$where the prime is $\partial/\partial x$ and $y$ is a function of $x$ and $z$. It is known that $[\partial f/\partial z]=x^0$ where $[]$ means dimensions relative to $x$. Also, $[a]=1/x$ where $a$ is a constant. It follows that the $\partial f/\partial z$ term does not contain any explicit dependence on $x$ and can then be treated as a constant in the integration with respect to $x$. An analytic solution can then be obtained.
But am I missing something by only using the fact that the dimensionality with respect to $x$ is $x^0$ to declare the partial $f$ term to not depend on $x$ in the integration with respect to $x$?

Comment: That's definitely not true because you have another dimensionfull parameter $a$. Then $ax$ is dimensionless and $\partial f/\partial z$ may be an arbitrary function of $ax$ so it could depend on $x$ and still be dimensionless.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Appreciate the response.